# When using effects, should the action be dispatch in the component or store?

Tags: angular, angular2-services, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I was pocking around the [echoes-player code](https://github.com/orizens/echoes-player), There use of effects is very clean, They have an effect in `player-dearch.effects` that listens to `PlayerSearchActions.SEARCH_MORE_FOR_QUERY`, this effects in turns calls the `searchMore` in `youtube.search` service.
The interesting part is that the action `searchMoreForQuery` is dispatched from the `youtube-videos.component`.

The question:
Someone said that it would be better to move the dispatching function to the 'youtube.search' service then to call that from the `youtube-videos.component`.
would that really be better design ?
is there any suggestions to improve this ?

```
@Effect()
  searchMoreForQuery$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(PlayerSearchActions.SEARCH_MORE_FOR_QUERY)
    .map(toPayload)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store)
    .map((latest: any[]) => latest[1])
    .filter((store: EchoesState) => !store.search.isSearching)
    .mergeMap((store: EchoesState) =>
      this.youtubeSearch.searchMore(store.search.pageToken.next)
      .search(store.search.query, store.search.queryParams)
      .map(youtubeResponse => this.playerSearchActions.searchResultsReturned(youtubeResponse)));
```